# How to use wtforms SelectField depending on dynamic attributes with flask & flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

In a flask app which has basically two attributes with a basic relation like this for example:

*models.py*

```
from . import db

class ProjectModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "projectmodels"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    projects = db.relationship("Project", backref="projectmodel", lazy="select")

class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "projects"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    project_model_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("projectmodels.id"), nullable=False)
```

When creating a `Project` object `wtforms` will have a `SelectField` depending on `projectmodels` on database.

My solution is defining a function returns a `list` for `SelectField[choices]` :

*forms.py*

```
from . import db
from wtforms import *

def projectmodels():
    models = ProjectModel.query.all()
    models_l = list()
    for model in models:
        models_l.append((str(model.id), model.name))
    return models_l

class AddProjectForm(Form):
    name = StringField(label="Project Name")
    project_model = SelectField("Project Model", 
                    choices=projectmodels())
```

While flask app running, `SelectField` lists all objects in database before app run. But during that session if any another project model is added, it won't list them until app is rerun.

Making all that form work in *routes.py* & `@app.route` section fixes this but that wouldn't be the best solution i guess.

What would be the solution for this?

Comment: PrettyPrinted did a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9W2ul2VRRc) on this using `QuerySelectField` from `wtforms-alchemy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.project_model.choices = [(a.id, a.name) for a in ProjectModel.query.order_by(ProjectModel.id)]
```

initializing this under `AddProjectForm` class solved the problem for me.